# List of obscure summation identities

Tags: polynomials, big-list, diophantine-equations

I am trying to evaluate a fairly simple summation:

$\sum_{k=1}^n ka^kb^{n-k}$

Which is related to the common identity for $\sum_{k=1}^n ka^k$ available on Wikipedia.

I've previously seen lengthy lists of obscure summation formulas in the comments but could not find any this time via the search function.

I found Henry Goulds list at https://dokumen.tips/documents/combinatorial-identities-a-standardized-set-of-tables-listing-500-binomial.html, but it only has formulas involving binomial coefficients.

Is there a list of obscure summation identities? And in particular is there a published identity for this sum?

I got to this sum after some operations on a difference of powers factorization.

Comment: Try out Wolfram Alpha. The code for your example is https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B+k+a+%5Ek+b%5E%28n-k%29+%2C+%7B+k%2C+1%2C+n+%7D+%5D

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of that! I did realize I could use the formula I listed by factoring out the $b^n$ term however. If you want to leave ur answer as an answer instead of a comment I will accept it, since it seems pretty general.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n ka^kb^{n-k}\ =\ b^n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\,k\cdot\left(\frac ab\right)^k$

Comment: Thre are books of summation identities, e.g., Jolley, Summation of Series. https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Summation_of_Series_Collected_by_L_B_W_J.html?id=at-0zQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: See the freely available reference in [this recent comment of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400819/an-infinite-series-that-converges-to-frac-sqrt3-pi24#comment1024258_400819).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the OP, I post my comment as an answer:

Try out Wolfram Alpha. The code for your example is https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B+k+a+%5Ek+b%5E%28n-k%29+%2C+%7B+k%2C+1%2C+n+%7D+%5D